# WPF / C# - Trying to get a value from a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a small time management app for myself (I'm only just starting out using C#/WPF).  However, I have become stuck on something that is driving me mad.  I have a form with a ListView, which is populated from a database (SQLite) - the binding/population seems to work fine (although I'm not sure if it's the right way).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to provide back the selected value (into something like a MessageBox).

I really could do with some help.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeMachine_WPF.MainActivitySub"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="Sub activities" Height="539" Width="478" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="451*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstActivitySub" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Activity_Category_Sub_Related}" SelectionChanged="lstActivitySub_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Add"  Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxNew" Height="23" Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;


namespace TimeMachine_WPF
{
    public partial class MainActivitySub : Window
    {
        public MainActivitySub()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + clVariables.strDB + "");
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT Activity_Category_Sub_Related FROM tblActivity_Sub", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tblActivity_Sub");
            lstActivitySub.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            lstActivitySub.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Activity_Category_Sub_Related"].ToString();
        }

        private void lstActivitySub_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This is where I need help!!!!
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `((ListBoxItem)lstActivitySub.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the UI Control in your code behind with its name.

`lstActivitySub.SelectedItem`

SelectedItem will be an object, so type cast it appropriately to access its value -

E.g.:

```
var dr=((DataRowView) (lstActivitySub.SelectedItem)).Row;
var message = dr["Activity_Category_Sub_Related"].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back so quickly, but when I add:  MessageBox.Show(lstActivitySub.SelectedItem); - I get a compile error.

Comment: It will be returning the item as an object. You have to type cast it to appropriate class like datatable/view. And access its property

Comment: Really sorry, but when I add: MessageBox.Show(((ListBoxItem)lstActivitySub.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());  It compiles just fine, but when I click on the box/change selection it comes up with an error.

Comment: @AndyDB can you post the error. It might throw error if the selection becomes null... Since yours looks like a sample app, you can write a condition to ignore null references

Comment: It was me.......Thank you so much to EVERYONE for your help (and patience) - I'm going to go back through everything a little later on and take on board all of the suggestions/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the selected listview item with:

```
String value = ((ListBoxItem)lstActivitySub.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` won't be of `ListBoxItem` type. It will be of the same type as provided `ItemsSource` item type. Your code will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
    private void lstActivitySub_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var data = e.AddedItems[0] as String;
        }
    }
```

Look into MVVM, it will help you abstract UI logic from data, and you will not be accessing controls directly from code.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFromList}" />
```

And have a ViewModel e.g.

```
public SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _itemsList;
    private object _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<object> ItemsList
    {
        get { return _itemsList; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _itemsList)) return;
            _itemsList = value;
            raisePropertyChanged("ItemsList");
        }
    }
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedItem)) return;
            _selectedItem = value;
            raisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the code behind:

```
public partial class YourWindow : Window
{
    public YourWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

And then handle the ItemChanged in the setter of `SelectedItem` in the view model

Comment: Thank you - I'll take a look at this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  void lstActivitySub_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = lstActivitySub.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lstActivitySub.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
        var Details = lstActivitySub.Items[lstActivitySub.SelectedIndex] as Activity_Category_Sub_Related;
    }
```

Comment: This one gives me a compile error @ 'as Activity_Category_Sub_Related;'  - Sorry, sure it's obvious, just starting out.